# WebShims is not working in IE9 for FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader, webshim

From the WebShims documents here at http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/filereader.html it is giving me an example of using FileReader with WebShims. Following it I have this code now

```
 <input class="ws-filereader" id="userFiles" multiple type="file"/>

 //Added Mordenizr and JQuery and WebShims library
 $.webshims.polyfill();

 $(function()
 { 
     $('#userFiles').on('change', function (evt) 
     { 
         var reader, file; 
         reader = new FileReader(); 
         reader.onload = function (evt) 
         { 
               var fileData = evt.target.result; 
         }; 
         file = $(this).prop('files')[0]; 
         reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
     }); 
 });
```

When I run this in IE9, It enters the code on change of userFiles but when I call to get

```
 console.log($(this).prop('files').length);
```

It gives 0. What's wrong with it?

When I turn on

```
 $.webshims.setOptions('debug', true);
```

console gives me

```
 Unable to get value of the property 'input': object is null or undefined.
```

There is a similar issue posted on its quesions https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader/issues/46 and it says that WebShims support IE9 for FileReader

Comment: Just run the code above in IE9 with Flash 12 and it works for me. Can you create a Fiddle showcasing the error[s]?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the files API was not introduced in IE until IE10:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This list of polyfills might be of use finding a workaround:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#wiki-file-api

Comment: But there documentation states that "That's why we have made WebShims to enhance browsers to support such features"

Comment: Note: that functionality relies on Adobe Flash.

Comment: Yes I know and Browser is flash enabled